# Spring boot application with EnableCaching How to retrieve guava cache content

Tags: spring, hibernate, guava, spring-test, spring-cache

It'm using a spring boot application with cache enabled.

Environment (pom.xml):

Spring:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE
org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:jar:1.0.4.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE
```

Hibernate

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final
org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4:jar:2.6.5
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.1.0.Final
org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:jar:5.1.0.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.1.0.Final
```

Configuration Cache (on Spring boot application):

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class ApplicationCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    /**
     * Configuration Table Cache
     */
    public static final String CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME = "CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE";

    public static final String CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_SERVICE_ID_CACHE_NAME = "CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_SERVICE_ID_CACHE";

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {

        SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        Collection<Cache> caches = Lists.newArrayList();

        caches.addAll(buildConfigurationCache());

        simpleCacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return simpleCacheManager;
    }

    private Collection<Cache> buildConfigurationCache() {

        List<Cache> caches = Lists.newArrayList();

        // This cache never expires and don't have a maximum size because the table Configuration is not transactional
        GuavaCache cacheFindById = new GuavaCache(CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME,
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build());
        caches.add(cacheFindById);

        // This cache never expires and don't have a maximum size because the table Configuration is not transactional
        GuavaCache cacheFindByService = new GuavaCache(CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_SERVICE_ID_CACHE_NAME,
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build());
        caches.add(cacheFindByService);

        return caches;
    }
}
```

Hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Configuration.TABLE_NAME)
@DynamicUpdate
public class Configuration implements Serializable {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "configuration";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Convert(converter = ConfigurationConverter.class)
    private ConfigurationEnum id;

    @Column(name = "service", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Convert(converter = ServiceConverter.class)
    private ServiceEnum service;

}
```

Repository (Spring-data):

```
public interface ConfigurationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Configuration, Integer>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Configuration> {

    @Cacheable(ApplicationCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME)
    Configuration findById(ConfigurationEnum configurationEnum);

    @Cacheable(ApplicationCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_SERVICE_ID_CACHE_NAME)
    List<Configuration> findByService(ServiceEnum service);

}
```

Configuration Enum:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum ConfigurationEnum {

    CONFIG_1(1),
    CONFIG_2(2);

    private int id;
}
```

Configuration Converter:

```
@Converter
public class ConfigurationConverter implements AttributeConverter<ConfigurationEnum, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(ConfigurationEnum key) {
        return key == null ? null : (int) key.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigurationEnum convertToEntityAttribute(Integer key) {

        return key == null ? null : Stream.of(ConfigurationEnum.values())
                     .filter(step -> key.equals(step.getId()))
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Test IT:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApplicationIT.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class ConfigurationCacheIT {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationRepository configurationRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Test
    public void configuration_findById_cache_success() {

        Configuration config = configurationRepository.findById(ConfigurationEnum.CONFIG_1);
        // An ORM request is performed - CHECK
        Assert.assertNotNull(step); // TEST OK
        Cache.ValueWrapper entry = getCacheEntry(ApplicationCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME, ConfigurationEnum.CONFIG_1.getId());
        Assert.assertNull(entry); OK

        config = configurationRepository.findById(ConfigurationEnum.CONFIG_1);
        // No ORM request is performed - CHECK
        Assert.assertNotNull(step); // TEST OK

        entry = getCacheEntry(ApplicationCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME, ConfigurationEnum.CONFIG_1.getId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(entry); **// TEST FAIL !!!**

        entry = getCacheEntry(ApplicationCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME, ConfigurationEnum.CONFIG_1.name());
        Assert.assertNotNull(entry); **// TEST FAIL !!!**

        entry = getCacheEntry(ApplicationCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME, ConfigurationEnum.CONFIG_1);
        Assert.assertNotNull(entry); **// TEST FAIL !!!**
    }

    protected Cache.ValueWrapper getCacheEntry(String cacheName, Object key) {
        return cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).get(key);
    }

    @Test
    public void configuration_findByAll_without_cache_success() {

    ArrayList<Configuration> list1 = Lists.newArrayList(configurationRepository.findAll());
    // An ORM request is executed
    Assert.assertNotNull(list1);
    Assert.assertEquals(ConfigurationEnum.values().length, list1.size());

    ArrayList<Configuration> list2 = Lists.newArrayList(configurationRepository.findAll());
    // Another ORM request is executed
    Assert.assertNotNull(list2);
    Assert.assertEquals(ConfigurationEnum.values().length, list2.size());
    }

}
```

My question is why my tests are failing?

Comment: The key is the enum not the name or id so those tests will simply always fail. Apparently in your tests, caching isn't enabled.

Comment: I think it is because as you see on the second request I put the comment  ``No ORM request is performed - CHECK``

Comment: That has nothing to do with caching, if you request the same entity from the first level cache nothign will happen and it will come from the 1st level cache i.e. directly from the `EntityManager`.

Comment: hum good point ... let's me review this

Comment: Actually @M.Deinum I performed a test using requests that are not being cached and the ORM requests are executed. Check the edited question (configuration_findByAll_without_cache_success test)

Comment: Please show us the source code for `ApplicationIT`.

Comment: ``@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationIT extends MyApplication { (...) mocking some beans but nothing related to hibernate or cache }``

Comment: Where's `@EnableCaching` on that one? Also you're reinventing the wheel there, Spring Boot could configure the Guava caches for you (check the doc).

Comment: @StephaneNicoll the annotation ``@EnableCaching`` is already defined on ApplicationCacheConfig. I don't understand your comment ... please expalin

Comment: This is the problem with sample like this. We can only guess. Rather than dumping a lot of code here, it would be 100 times more effective if you'd share a sample on github that we can run. Is that file scanned by the class you've specified in your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was a non issue.

I'm using the fallowing architecture:

- **App-mdw** (Middleware layer) (Spring boot App with @EnableCaching annotation)
- **App-ws** (WebServices layer) (Spring boot App without @EnableCaching annotation)

The above tests were executed on the application **App-ws** and the annotation is not inherited that's why the caching was not working.

The right assert was:

```
entry = getCacheEntry(ApplicationCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_TABLE_FIND_BY_ID_CACHE_NAME, ConfigurationEnum.CONFIG_1);
        Assert.assertNotNull(entry)
```